# Black kicked out and Pettigrew recoiled

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Context - Pettigrew is grovelling on his knees.

> Black kicked out and Peter recoiled.

My research :
Now this could mean two things.

1. Black literally kicked him and Peter got pushed away through the impact of the kick.
2. Black just kicked his leg at his direction (not actually kicking him) and Pettigrew just flinched backwards.

Now which one is correct here?
**And more importantly, how do you determine that?**

Comment: I'm sure it's the second meaning. That's primarily a matter of ***pragmatics*** rather than the exact words used, but I would say that an inanimate thing like a *gun* "recoils" as Newton's "equal and opposite reaction" when discharging a bullet. By the same token, when a *person* recoils, the movement is nearly always ***their own muscles flinching*** (caused by surprise, shock), not a result of ***external force*** (being ***hit***).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it probably could be either. But if the first was intended, it would have been better to say "Black kicked Peter".  The image of Peter as a person who would recoil rather than hit back fits his character.

So it is probably the second meaning that is intended.